# TASM - unrecognized argument

Tags: assembly, z80

I'm trying to write a small z80 program for a ti-84+ and TASM doesn't recognize  my arguments for the `OUT` instruction.

This *should* be the syntax for the `OUT` instruction, but TASM doesn't seem to recognize it.

`OUT ($10) , $05`

Expected Result: no errors, but the actual result is `unrecognized argument.             (($10),$05)`

Comment: Is that TASM, as in the Turbo Assembler, the old x86 assembler?

Comment: `OUT ($10) , $05` <-- Where did you get that example from? There's no `OUT (n), n` on the Z80 that I'm aware of. There's `OUT (n), A` and `OUT (C), R`.

Comment: Please provide a link to the TASM you use and its version if appropriate. You see, there is more than one TASM. And then tell us what you like to do. As @Michael said there is no `OUT (n),d` on the Z80. Please [edit] your question, don't hide additional information in a comment. Make sure you took the [tour] and learn [ask].

Comment: I would also like to throw in that for the Z80, spasm-ng is an excellent, modern assembler, which also has TI-8x specific tools. TASM is ancient at this point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had this same problem before, the fix is that you cannot give a number to the `OUT` opcode, you need to use a register. The new code that you would need would be the following

```
LD A, $05
OUT ($10), A
```

Another thing about the LCD screen ports is they are slow so i also recommend putting a delay after each use put,

```
_LCD_BUSY_QUICK    .EQU    $000B
```

At the beginning of your program because its the easiest delay. so the final code will be,

```
LD A, $05
OUT ($10), A
call _LCD_BUSY_QUICK
```

Also tasm is very old and slow so if you get into programming more i recommend spasm as its faster, also if you choose to use spasm, run it through Command Prompt as its much easier then using visual studio and because you use tasm i assume you are already accustomed to using command prompt.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Ah that makes sense.  An instruction with 2 immediates would have to be larger, and more complex to decode.  Not surprising that Z80 doesn't provide it.